# Loading data from SharePoint Excel using Management Console

Tags: sharepoint, qlikview

I load data into QlikView from a SharePoint Excel-file and get the error: Bad Zip File. But if I sign into SharePoint using QlikView "Open Url..." and then enter my SharePoint credentials, and reload QlikView the script works fine.

But when I use the Management Console to reload a scheduled job, I get the error again: Bad Zip File. And it is because my user isn't signed in. How can I get SharePoint to have the user signed in when the Management Console reloads the scheduled job?

Answer (score 1):

Most setups have QDS (the Distribution Service that reloads QVWs) running under a named account, so you might need to coordinate with your Sharepoint admin to see that that particular account has read access to the .zip file. If you end up finding that QDS uses an account that's local to the QDS server, you might do well to setup a centralized non-human account (on your LDAP or Active Directory, whatever your company uses) to perform the reload...and then have your Sharepoint admin grant access.